# Xamarin Form Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: 'Camera permission(s) are required.'

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hola amigos estoy tratando de acceder  a mi camara desde **Xamarin Forms** usando `Xam.Plugin.Media` , bueno todo bien pero no tengo problemas con los permisos.
Este es el mensaje que me tira

> Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: 'Camera permission(s) are required.'

Este es mi `Manifest`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.miapp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

  <application android:label="SUMATEAPPT2.Android" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="miapi" />
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
              android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
              android:exported="false"
              android:grantUriPermissions="true">

      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                       android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

este es mi `AssemblyInfo`

```
    using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Android.App;

// General Information about an assembly is controlled through the following 
// set of attributes. Change these attribute values to modify the information
// associated with an assembly.
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("miapp.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("miapp.Android")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©  2014")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]


// [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]

// Add some common permissions, these can be removed if not needed
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage)]


[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera", Required = false)]
[assembly: UsesFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus", Required = false)]
```

y mi  metodo es este

```
 private async  void btnCamara_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera avaialble.", "OK");
            return;
        }
        var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
        {
            Directory = "Sample",
            Name = "test.jpg"
        });
        if (file == null)
            return;
        await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");
        // await App.MasterD.Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Photox());
    }
```

Esta es la forma en como llamo a mi metodo.

```
            <Button x:Name="btnCamara" 
                Text="Cam Connectivity  " 

                Clicked="btnCamara_Clicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
```

esta es mi fuente, alguien sabe si me estoy pasando algo?
https://xamarinlatino.com/usando-plugin-media-en-xamarin-forms-97226c55b85c

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega los métodos que ejecutas donde "inicializas" los formularios

Comment: prueba a llamar a la cámara dentro de un bloque try

Comment: por cierto, has verificado en tu dispositivo los permisos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bueno volviendo a leer me di cuenta que en el archivo `MainActivity` de android me hacia falta esta liena
 `CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);`

justo debajo del `OnCreate` y listo eso pide los permisos antes ejecutar solo la primera vez.

Comment: creo que no es solo la primera vez, es cada vez que la cámara no tenga los permisos, los puedes modificar cuando quieras desde ajustes de la aplicación

Comment: justo lo que te pedía en el comentario de la pregunta :D me alegra que te hayas dado cuenta. ¡Buena suerte con el desarrollo móvil, vas por buen camino! :D